# If $x = A\mid B$ is a cut in $\mathbb{Q}$, show that $x = \text{l.u.b. } A.$

Tags: real-analysis

**The question:**

If $x = A\mid B$ is a cut in $\mathbb{Q}$, show that $x = \text{l.u.b. } A.$

**The definitions:**

A **cut** in $\mathbb{Q}$ is a pair of subsets $A, ~B$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that

(a) $A \cup B = \mathbb{Q}, ~ A \neq \emptyset, ~ B \neq \emptyset, ~ A \cap B = \emptyset.$

(b) If $a \in A \text{ and } b \in B \text{ then } a < b.$

(c) $A$ contains no largest element.

**Work so far:**

$A =  \{ a \in \mathbb{Q} : a < x  \}$

$B = \text{ rest of } \mathbb{Q}$

It is clear from the definition of the cut that $x$ is an upper bound for $A$. My idea was to show that if $x \neq \text{l.u.b. } A$ then there must exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every element $ a \in A$ the following holds

$a < x- \epsilon$

which cannot be true because *insert reason* and we reach a contradiction. This is where I'm stuck. I want to say "because I can find $a \in A$ which is greater then $x- \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$" but I feel very uneasy with this.

I just started studying real analysis and have very little background in proving stuff so this is all new to me. For this particular example I feel like there is nothing to prove, as if it is clear from the definition of the cut that $x$ is a l.u.b. so a nice complete proof would be extremely helpful to me.

Comment: What does $A|B$ mean?

Comment: It is defined in the question.

Comment: $A \vert B$ is a notation for a cut where $A$ represents the left-hand part of the cut and $B$ represents the right-hand side. A cut is defined in the post.

Comment: Now I understand, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is not the least upper bound. This implies that there exists a real $y$ with $a < y< x$ for all $a\in A$.

Now you can use that between any two real numbers there is a rational (I don't know what axioms exactly you are using in your class, but this should have been proven). So there is  $q\in\mathbb Q$ with $y<q<x$.

But then $a<q$ for all $a\in A$, so $q\in B$. This contradicts the fact that $q\in A$ (from $q<x$).

The contradiction shows that there is no upper bound for $A$ less than $x$, so $x$ is the least upper bound.

Comment: Great, thank you very much. Is it allowed to use real numbers in the proof involving cuts? Real numbers are defined as being cuts in $\mathbb{Q}$ so this seems a bit odd.

Comment: It is a matter of language. In which sense is your $x$ an upper bound for all elements of $A$? What does $a<x$ mean, since $x$ is not a number? I don't know your context so I cannot use definitions that I don't have. But, in the end, however it is done it will be equivalent.

Comment: @Gordan Everything that was said about real numbers in this answer, is also true for rational numbers so you can just replace the word.

Comment: Yes, It is clear now, thank you.
@GitGud Indeed, thank you.